# Using @State in my viewmodel and have it update my UI

Tags: swiftui

I want to have a @State property in my ViewModel.

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi all")
            ContentView2(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView2: View {
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

        var body: some View {
            Text("Hi all")
                .modifier(GeometryGetter(rect: viewModel.$dynamicRect))
        }
    }
    
    public struct GeometryGetter: ViewModifier {
        @Binding var rect: CGRect
        
        public init(rect: Binding<CGRect>) {
            self._rect = rect
        }
        
        public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            return GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.rect = proxy.frame(in: .global)
                }
                return Color.clear
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @State var dynamicRect: CGRect = .zero
    }
}
```

Problem is that i'm getting this error:

```
Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update
```

Is this doable? I tried looking for information about holding the @State in the viewmodel buy couldn't find something too useful

Comment: When you want to use a property of an observable object that way the correct property wrapper is @PublishedProperty.

Comment: Ok, but then, can I link it to @Binding in inner views?

Comment: Yeah. should work no problem. State, PublishedProperty, StateObject, ObservedObject are all just ways to create bindings from different types of objects.

Comment: I'm getting:

"Cannot convert value of type 'Published<CGRect>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<CGRect>'"

Comment: I set it as a different question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592014/connecting-published-and-binding